# Python: Swapping two strings within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Okay, so I am having a problem swapping part of a string with part of another string in a list. I've seen the other similar questions on this site but none of them seem to work for me.

Let's say I have a list:

```
sentList = ['i like math', 'i am a cs expert']
```

Now I want to switch 'math' with 'cs' using variables determined by user input.

```
currentWord = input('Swap word: ')
newWord = input('with word: ')
```

So, now how would I swap the two so that my list would return the following:

```
sentList = ['i like cs', 'i am a math expert']
```

As always, thank you for any help. I think I can use the replace function but am not sure how. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
sentList = [sentListN.replace(currentWord, newWord) for sentListN in sentList]
```

But, obviously that does not work.

Comment: Lot of ambiguity in the question. Many scenarios possible here, like the one @Delgan mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single liner using `list comprehension`.

```
[sent.replace(currentWord,newWord) if sent.find(currentWord)>=0 else sent.replace(newWord,currentWord) for sent in sentList]
```

So,

```
IN: sentList = ['i like math', 'i am a cs expert']
IN : currentWord = "math"
IN : newWord = "cs"
OUT : ['i like cs', 'i am a math expert']
```

Here, `if sent.find('math')>=0` will find out if the string conntains `'math'`  , and if so, replaces it with `'cs'`, else it replaces `'cs'` with `'math'`. In case the string contains neither, then too it will print the original, as replace only works if the substring is found.

---

**Edit :** as [@Rawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420146/python-swapping-two-strings-within-a-list/46420532#comment79798458_46420532) pointed out, there were a few bugs in the above code. So here is the new code that will handle every and all cases.

I have used `re.sub` to handle replacement of **only words**, and the replacement algorithm is that of how you would swap two variables, say for `x` and `y`, where we introduce a temporary variable `t` to help with the swap:  `t = x; x = y; y = t`. This approach was chosen since we have to do **Multiple substitution at the same time**.

```
from re import sub

for s in sentList:

  #replace 'math' with '%math_temp%' in s (here '%math_temp%' is a dummy placeholder that we need to later substitute with 'cs')
  temp1 = sub(r'\bmath\b','%math_temp%' , s)

  #replace 'cs' with 'math' in temp1
  temp2 = sub(r'\bcs\b','math', temp1)

  #replace '%math_temp%' with 'cs' in temp2
  s = sub('%math_temp%','cs', temp2)

  print(s)
```

So this time on a bigger test case, we get :

```
IN : sentList = ['i like math', 'i am a cs expert', 'math cs', 'mathematics']
IN : currentWord = "math"
IN : newWord = "cs"

OUT : i like cs
      i am a math expert
      cs math
      mathematics
```

Comment: Note that this will turn `"math cs"` into `"cs cs"`. It'll also turn `"mathematics"` into `"csematics"`.

Comment: Hmmm. True @Rawing. Let me change that. Thanks for the headsup

Comment: @DakotaBrown, there is a slight logical error as Rawing pointed out. For simple use this is fine, but for complicated situations this fails.

Comment: I am working up a better logic. Will update again in a few @DakotaBrown

Comment: I see, please let me know when you do.

Comment: @DakotaBrown , check out the new and improved version :D

Answer (score 1):

The following code works. I used word1 (currentWord) and word2 (newWord) variables as user input

```
sentList = ['i like math', 'i am a cs expert']

word1 = 'math'
word2 = 'cs'

assert word1, word2 in sentList
sentList = [s.replace(word1, word2) if word1 in s
           else s.replace(word2, word1) if word2 in s
           else s for s in sentList]
```

If we break it down to steps, it looks like

```
for i, s in enumerate(sentList):
    if word1 in s:
        sentList[i] = s.replace(word1, word2)
    elif word2 in s:
        sentList[i] = s.replace(word2, word1)
```

Comment: This'll turn `"math cs"` into `"cs cs"` and `"mathematics"` into `"csematics"`.

Comment: I ended up using another one, but this worked. Thank you, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by simple swap function. Don't need to complicate code :)

```
def swap(str, x, y):
    words = []
    for w in str.split():
        if w == x:
            words.append(y)
        elif w == y:
            words.append(x)
        else:
            words.append(w)
    return ' '.join(words)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentList = ['i like math', 'i am a cs expert']
    word1 = 'math'
    word2 = 'cs'
    new_list = [swap(x, word1, word2) for x in sentList]
    print(new_list)
```

Comment: This was actually really useful in terms of learning, but I am not allowed to use a function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each sentence only contains one word (a sentence can't contain both `math` and `cs`) just make a new list and append new strings to it:

```
newSentList = []
for sent in sentList:
    assert(currentWord in sent != newWord in sent)
    if currentWord in sent:
        newSentList.append(sent.replace(currentWord, newWord))
    else:
        newSentList.append(sent.replace(newWord, currentWord))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
In [20]: currentWord = 'cs'

In [21]: newWord = 'math'

In [22]: [i.replace(currentWord,newWord) if  currentWord in i else i.replace(newWord,currentWord) if newWord in i else i for i in sentList]
Out[22]: ['i like cs', 'i am a math expert']
```

It's a simple combination of `list comprehension` and `if else` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a naive answer (words can be substrings of other words, etc), but following your approach, we can swap `wa` with `wb` by

```
wa=input....
wb=input....
new = [s.replace(wa,"_").replace(wb,wa).replace("_",wb) for s in sentList]
```

this way a sentence with both is transformed the following way:

"cs is older then math" --> "_ is older then math" --> "_ is older then cs" --> "math is older then cs"

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `s.replace` chaining? How does this work?